Gboard 3x4 numeric keypad in text fields
How can I use the 3x4 numerical pad in an input field that allows for input other than numbers? For example, input fields that don't have <input type="number"> set in a browser.
Related resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number
Screenshot of ideal numerical pad:


If you are using gboard (like you have tagged your post), you can use a version of the 3x4 number pad on any application.

Open Google Messages (or any app)

Tap on the text field

Tap on the number/symbol pad labeled with "?123" on the bottom left of the keyboard


Tap on the icon with 4 vertical numbers labeled "1234" to the right of the comma


Doing this will have a result of a 3x4 number pad that is pretty similar to the one used in numerical input fields.




The 3×4 pad looks like that but mine has letters on the numbers. Like #2 is ABC #3 is DEF and so on. It allows me to type faster, since I'm old school. I also have the QWERTY keypad. I just want to know if gboard has that texting option since my phone is asking me to upgrade to the gboard.  I don't want to if it's going to make the 3x4 disappear or make it obsolete.  I can't find an answer anywhere on Google.

Thank you. My phone is asking me to update my messages, but I use the 3x4 text pad to text with. I like it better than the QWERTY keyboard, which I have. I just want to know if updating gboard will make my 3x4 disappear. I can't find the answer on Google anywhere.  Thanks for replying.

@Bruneman88 Upgrading google messages shouldn't change your keyboard. Your default keyboard is actually a seperate app on your phone. You should be able to upgrade google messages without changing your keyboard. If you change your keyboard to gboard, however, it will look like those in my above screenshot (meaning you won't be able to type 10-key text, which I believe is what you're referring to when you mean #2 is ABC and #3 is DEF).

Yes that's what I'm talking about. Thanks.  I thought every android phone had that keyboard option?  So basically don't change my keyboard to Gboard?

@Bruneman88 Yes, don't change your keyboard to Gboard, and you can upgrade Google Messages without changing your keyboard. Different device manufacturers usually also put different keyboards on their devices (For example, Samsung Keyboard is usually the default on Samsung Phones, Gboard is usually the default on Google Phones). This also allows you to download new keyboards from the app store if you don't like the default.

Well thank you. That definitely helps.   Appreciate the time you took.  Happy holidays!
